# List of Base Interfaces vs Individual Specialized Interfaces in Factory class

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface

**ServiceManager** class runs and stops the processes on threads. All processes will implement the **IImportProcess** interface. Is it a good idea to use a list of IImportProcess so that in the future if a new process is implemented there would be no change in the ServiceManager, or use subtypes of IImportProcess that will require changes in the ServiceManager but improve object orientation?

```
public ServiceManager(IEnumerable<IImportProcess> importProcesses, ILogger logger){ }
```

or

`public ServiceManager(IProductImportProcess productImportProcesses, IAuthorImportProcess authorImportProcesses, ILogger logger)`

Comment: "improve object orientation" how? If the code explicitly needs a product import process, an author import process, and nothing else, you should go for the explicit version. If the code explicitly needs "all import processes regardless of what they are", then you should go for the collection version.

Comment: If IEnumerable<IImportProcess> fits in your scenario, go for it! As you said in future new process may be implemented.

Comment: In other words, if your current constructor takes in a collection, and then you go hunting in that collection for the right 2-3 services, then use the explicit parameters. If you need and intend to use them all, collection.